# Max. number of parallel reads for a single object

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In Google Group Mike[1] wrote:

> Google Cloud Storage does support parallel *reads* within a single file [...]

How many parallel reads were allowed (for one single file)? I ask because my application throws an exception if I try to access a single file with parallel requests (Google App Engine Java API).

Maybe the application throws the exception because the request is open for more than 30 seconds (I will check that now). But it is also necessary for me to know how many requests I can send for one single file.

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/gs-discussion/concurrent/gs-discussion/5K9rReneQK8/v7QEbSx4cY8J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage has no hard limit on the number of parallel requests to an object. Parallel requests from the same application are usually used to retrieve parts of a large object using the HTTP Range header:

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#range